# Passing comma separated numbers as a SQL Parameter

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I have query for which i am using binding variables. the query is like

```
Select...
From....
where Ids1 in (@SQLParameter1)
and  Ids2 in (@SQLParameter2)
and Ids3 in (@SQLParameter3)
```

I have values for `@SQLParameter1`, `@SQLParameter2`, `@SQLParameter3` in string format all numbers comma sepearated. I mentioned SQLParameter dataType as string but Ids1, Ids2, Ids3 are numeric columns so it throws error. I tried DataType as Varnumeric but it didnt work.

> So how do you pass comma separated numbers as a SQL Parameter???

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass only one value per command parameter. A list of values is not possible like this.

You will have to construct the SQL dynamically.

```
string sql = String.Format(
    "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id1 IN ({0}) AND id2 IN ({1}) AND id3 IN ({2})",
    id1List, id2List, id3List
);
```

But beware of SQL-injection. Depending on where the id lists come from, you will have to choose a more complicated approach and to create parameter lists dynamically.

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE
    id1 IN (@1, @2, @3, @4) AND
    id2 IN (@5, @6, @7) AND
    id3 IN (@8, @9)
```

---

I do not know if this is the case, but if the three ids build a primary key, this approach will not select unique primary key combinations. In that case the query must look like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE
    (id1 = @1 AND id2 = @2 AND id3 = @3) OR
    (id1 = @4 AND id2 = @5 AND id3 = @6) OR
    (id1 = @7 AND id2 = @8 AND id3 = @9)
```

Comment: Solution -1. I can construst the query dynamically but using binding variables as it improves performance.  Solution 2 and 3 is not useful in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 you could create a stored procedure with table-valued parameters for each collection of Id's.  See below:

```
CREATE TYPE SQLParameter1TableType AS TABLE 
( 
    Id INT
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestStoredProcedure
(
    @SQLParameter1 SQLParameter1TableType READONLY
)
AS

Select...
From....
where Ids1 in (@SQLParameter1)
GO

DECLARE @SQLParameter1 AS SQLParameter1TableType;

INSERT INTO @SQLParameter1 (Id)
...select from

EXEC dbo.TestStoredProcedure @SQLParameter1;
```

Of course if you're using ADO.NET then here is a useful article that will show you how use table valued parameters with .NET (you will need to convert the language to VB.NET): http://orionseven.com/blog/2009/09/30/using-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-c/

Here is the MSDN article for SQL Server Table Valued Parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

....Alternatively you could pass in a comma seperated string into SQL Table-Valued function that splits the string and returns a table with a single column:

```
SELECT...
FROM....
where Ids1 in (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(@SQLParameter1))
```

...or you could create a scalar function that accepts an Id and checks if it exists in the supplied comma seperated string, returning true/false accordingly:

```
SELECT...
FROM.... AS T
WHERE dbo.ExistsInCommaSeperatedString(T.Id, @SQLParameter1) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I handled this with dynamic SQL and a quick regex to throw out anything that isn't a number or a comma.  I *think* this protects things.  Is there a SQL injection attack involving only numbers and commas?  I'd love to get a definite answer on that.  But here's what I did, in vb.net:

intStr = "1001,1002,1003"

Dim RegexObj As Regex = New Regex("[^\d|^\,]")

If RegexObj.IsMatch(intStr) Then
    intStr = "0"
End If

SQL = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID IN (" & intStr & ")"
etc..

Answer (score 0):

in C# through ADO.NET we can pass comma seperated values below:

string intTransIds = string.Join(",", intTransId.ToArray());
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@intTransIDs", DbType.String, intTransIds);

and stored procedure side we can make a variable @intTransIDs varchar(max) to handle comma seperated string.